# How to have Ubuntu be recognized by host name from a Windows network

Tags: 14.04

I have an Ubuntu device and a Windows PC in the same domain LAN with Windows in my office DHCP domain "value-tech.com". I'm exporting a Samba folder from Ubuntu.

Type $hostname of Ubuntu is "david_samba"

I can access my Samba folder from Windows with an IP address but cannot with the host name,

I can ping Ubuntu with an IP address, or type \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in Windows File Explorer to access Ubuntu

Below is my "smb.conf" clip section

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
#security = share
netbios name = david_samba
wins server = value-tech.com
```

How can I type \david_samba then I can access it from Windows File Explorer to avoid problems when DHCP changes the Ubuntu IP address from time to time?

Or, should I modify /etc/nsswitch.conf to make my hostname work on the Windows DNS network?

I tried to search for a method on Google but without success.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is name resolution. You need your LAN PCs to correctly resolve the name 'david_samba'.  Everything else is working - if you enter the IP manually, you can browse the share on david_samba.

So, all you need to do is get name resolution working. This is called DNS. You need to get your LAN PCs to resolve the host name 'david_samba'. Your LAN PCs can get local name resolution from your LAN's DNS resolver - so if the LAN's DNS resolver knows the IP of the david_samba machine, then so too will the LAN PCs.

You mention DHCP in your LAN. If it is correctly configured, your DHCP server will update your LAN's DNS resolver with any IPs it issues.  You can configure your DHCP server to issue a specific IP to your david_samba machine, and this will then update the DNS resolver in your LAN.

So, if your DNS and DHCP servers (they may be services on the same machine) are correctly configured, then all you need to do is set your DHCP server to issue david_samba with a static IP. The david_samba machine should be configured to get its ip via DHCP.

So long as the other machines on the network use the same DNS resolver, they will then be able to resolve \david_samba to \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

Once this is working you will be able to access the share on Windows with \hostname\sharename.

A simple test is to use 'ping':  ping david_samba  and see if the name is translated to an IP address and then replies are received. What you are looking for is that the test machine can use the name to find the IP address of the david_samba machine.

If you don't have control over your LAN's DNS and DHCP servers, you can do a quick workaround by adding an entry into your local machine's hosts file. 
add an entry like this: (all on one line)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx machine_name
eg:  `192.168.1.25  david_samba`

On a Windows 10 PC the hosts file is here:  c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

- you need Administrator permissions to edit this file.

This will work immediately and is great for testing or if you just want to get this working on your own PC.  It is not a suitable solution for lots of PCs because the hosts file on every one has to be edited (and again if ever the IP of david_samba changes).  If you want the solution to work across multiple PCs you need to get your local name resolution (DNS) working.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also How do I write a good answer? for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: extensively revised, as requested